# pass a string of greek character in mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

```
insertStudentData:function(school_id,studentData,callback){


var _pass_student=Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 8);
var _pass_father=Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 8);
var _pass_mother=Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 8);


    var data = [
        { tag: '_father_pass', value : _pass_father },
        { tag: '_mother_pass', value : _pass_mother },
       { tag: '_student_pass', value :_pass_student }];
            enc_data.getpass(8, data, function(result){

        query= 'call addStudentBulk("'+studentData[12]+'",'+studentData[15]+','+studentData[16]+',"'+studentData[1]+'","'+studentData[3]+'","'+studentData[2]+'","'+studentData[7]+'","'                            +studentData[4]+'","'+studentData[6]+'","'+studentData[13]+'","'+studentData[8]+'","'+studentData[14]+'","'+studentData[10]+'","'+studentData[11]+'","'+studentData[5]+'","'+studentData[9]+'","'+_pass_student+'","'+_pass_father+'","'+_pass_mother+'","'+result[2]['value']+'","'+result[0]['value']+'","'+result[1]['value']+'",'+school_id+')';

 dataAccess.getObject(query,function(status){

        if(status!='err')
        {
            console.log(studentData[12]+' '+studentData[1]+' done');
                      callback({err:false,data:null});

        }
       else
        {
            console.log(studentData[12]+' '+studentData[1]+ ' err');
    callback({err:true,data:studentData[12]+' '+studentData[1]+ ' err'});
        }
                                });
```

});
},

I have table with column name varchar(50).  I can easily set greek characters in insert query like this:

```
insert into student set name='ΧΡΙΣΤΟΣ ΑΒΕΡΚΙΟΥ';
```

But when I pass this greek character string to mysql stored procedure through in parameters it gives me this error:

```
call new_procedure('ΧΡΙΣΤΟΣ ΑΒΕΡΚΙΟΥ');

Error Code: 1366. Incorrect string value: '\xCE\xA7\xCE\xA1\xCE\x99...' for 
column 'name_'
```

Here is my body of procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`(in name_ varchar(45) )

 BEGIN
 INSERT INTO `student` (`student_name`) VALUES (name_);
 END
```

How can I do that? Please help me.
Edit

I have already set the table to utf8;
I am importing data from excel sheet in NodeJs. excel sheet contains greek characters and i want to store them as it is.here is picture of table structure
[image: table structure]

Comment: Your string is encoded as UTF-8. Part of your toolchain is not configured to use such encoding. Please edit the question and share: 1) Your table definition 2) The JavaScript code where you set the connection encoding.

Comment: It's alright. If you reconsider your hypothesis feel free the provide the information requested and I'll be happy to have a look at it.

Comment: what else do u need @ÁlvaroGonzález. ?

Comment: If possible: 1) Your table definition 2) The JavaScript code where you set the connection encoding.

Comment: javascript code is above here studentData is object of excel sheet  is array of array (array of rows of excel sheet). im accesing by indexing like studentData[2] and so on .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130209/discussion-between-asad-and-alvaro-gonzalez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message illustrates, your string is properly encoded as UTF-8 but MySQL Server did not expect it. It isn't entirely clear if you actually want to use UTF-8 but we are in 2016 so we'll assume you do.

First of all, you need to inspect your table structure. If you didn't keep the original `CREATE TABLE` statement (or it never existed because you used a GUI tool to create the table both in development and production) you can obtain it with this query:

```
show create table student
```

Your table should use UTF-8 explicitly. Otherwise, you'll depend on whatever default value was used by whoever created the database. You post a picture of some GUI tool that suggests that the `student_name` column uses UTF-8 but may have a different encoding that the rest of the table: if true, that's a signal of problems waiting to happen (but would not be the source of your current problem). Whatever, don't guess, just see it with your own eyes.

Secondly, I've googled for mysql libraries for Node.js and chose the first result (assuming you did the same) and found [mysqljs/mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql). That one appears to not support anything else than UTF-8 so it doesn't even have an "encoding" parameter but, once more, you should actually verify it by yourself (after all, this might not even be your library).

---

If you don't really want to use UTF-8, please disregard this answer: it doesn't apply to your problem.

Comment: thank u for ur great time @Alvaru i managed to do it in local . still getting issue in live. will work on it

Answer (score 0):

Without know all of the details, I would say that the table is not encoded for Greek characters.  UTF-8 should be able to handle Greek characters.

```
ALTER TABLE `student` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
```

Secondly, you need to make sure text in which you are importing is encoded in UTF-8.  If you are writing from your webpage then you can define the character set in the meta tags.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

If you are importing from a CSV, you can copy the data into notePad++ and it should be able to encode the text into UTF-8.

Comment: i am importing data from excel sheet.xlsx

Comment: this works fine if i simple insert through query but dnt work with procedure :(